# How to activate API Bigquery in GCP with python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am developing a small application in gcp and I must activate the bigquery api to interact with it, I do it through the console, but, Is it possible to do it with the python google api client?

I've been looking in the documentation but it's still not clear to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That is done through [the services API](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable `BigQuery API` from console:

- Go to **console.google.com**
- From the menu, click on **APIs & Services ->Enable APIs & Service**
- Click on **Enable APIs and Service**
- Search for **BigQuery API** and click on enable

To enable through `gcloud sdk`:

```
gcloud services enable bigquery.googleapis.com
```

You may need to enable other BigQuery related APIs as well:

```
bigquery.googleapis.com                BigQuery API
bigqueryconnection.googleapis.com      BigQuery Connection API
bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com    BigQuery Data Transfer API
bigquerymigration.googleapis.com       BigQuery Migration API
bigquerystorage.googleapis.com         BigQuery Storage API
```

To enable a service through python [REST refer this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/enable)

To interact/work with BigQuery using Python client library:

Install the `Python Client library for BigQuery`:

```
install google-cloud-bigquery
```

Query stack overflow public dataset:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

# Perform a query.
QUERY = ("SELECT title FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` LIMIT 10")
query_job = client.query(QUERY)  # API request
rows = query_job.result()  # Waits for query to finish

for row in rows:
    print(row.name)
```

Reference: BigQuery [QuickStart using client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python)